# OpenCL code 'Error MSB3721' for Intel OpenCL SDK on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencl, gpu

I am currently using Intel's OpenCL SDK platform for heterogeneous parallel programming (OpenCL). I am using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate for this. My system doesn't have any GPU in it. I have worked on CUDA SDK platform for opencl programming. This the first time I am using Intel's OpenCL SDK for opencl programming.

I have tried some basic platform, device, context identifying/creating/defining codes from 'OpenCL in Action' book. They all worked fine. So we can consider that visual studio is properly configured.

Now, I am trying to build a 'Hello World' program in visual studio which gives me following error:

**Error MSB3721: The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x86\ioc32.exe" -cmd=build -input="E:\Menu\Google\programs\1code\feb\10feb2014\OpenCL\OpenCL\hello.cl" -output="Debug\hello.out" -VS -device=CPU -simd=default    -bo="           "" exited with code -1073741511.    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\BuildCustomizations\IntelOpenCL.targetS**

Now my questions are:

1. What is the significance of this 'Error MSB3721'?
2. Is this a programming related error or something is wrong with the 'OpenCL + Visual Studio' configuration?

I am trying to be as specific as possible in this question. Let me know if I have not providing enough information and help me out. I really appreciate your concern.

Comment: Is that the only error you get? Can you check the error list window?

Comment: #Oak - Yes this what I am getting. There is nothing else in the error list window.

Comment: Then I don't know what this is :( You should consider also asking on the [official support forum for Intel OpenCL SDK](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-opencl-sdk).

Comment: Do you have latest Intel OpenCL SDK & CPU-only runtime package? Intel's SDK goes up with "kernel builder" application - can you debug any simplest kernel in it?

Comment: #Roman Arzumanyan - Yes Roamn, I have latest SDKs. I have executed opencl's vector addition program on the same system before. Also I have executed basic platform, device, context identifying/creating/defining codes from 'OpenCL in Action' book. 
I guess there is problem with the SDKs only. I think I should try re-installing sdks.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?  If not, for older Intel CPUs, there is an OpenCL runtime that might need to be installed.  Does that help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know what it is, but i had the same problem when there was some *.cl file in my project. Just remove it from project (not from disk)! Anyway you will be able to read your source from this *.cl file, but when this file presents in project it causes en error. I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

I think the cause of the error is Intel codebuilder configuration or infinite loop in .cl file.

Please check if your error can be resolved by below two changes.

1. If you build your project as the Codebuilder project (e.g. Empty Opencl Project for Windows), 
   1-1. Right click your project and select **properties**

   1-2. Select **OpenCL Code Builder** tab

   1-3. If your device is configured as Intel(R) CPU (-device=CPU), then change it to your GPU device (e.g. **Intel(R) Graphics (-device=GPU)** in my case)
2. If you face the same error, then check if your **.cl file** contains the infinite loop such as **while(1) or for(;;)**

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same error. Changing solution platform from x32 to x64 fixed it (I've got x64 machine).