# Separate .cl files not working. Error MSB3722

Tags: visual-studio-2015, opencl

In Visual Studio 2015, I create a 'Code Build Project for Windows' (for a CPU). This project comes with code that I have not touched at all. It essentially does vector addition. However, the vector addition takes place on a Template.cl file. When I try to compile this project, it gives me the following error:

> Error  MSB3722 The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\bin\x86\ioc32.exe" -cmd=build -input="blahblah\user\visual studio 2015\Projects\OpenCLProject3\OpenCLProject3\Template.cl" -output="Debug\Template.out" -VS -device=CPU_2_0 -simd=default -targetos=current        -bo="           "" exited with code 5. Please verify that you have sufficient rights to run this command.  OpenCLProject3  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\BuildCustomizations\IntelOpenCL.targets  98

But if I copy the kernel into my cpp file and have it as a string, then it executes. The string looks like this:

```
const char* prog1 = "__kernel void Add(__global int* pA, __global int* pB, __global int* pC){const int x = get_global_id(0);const int y = get_global_id(1);const int width = get_global_size(0);const int id = y * width + x;pC[id] = pA[id] + pB[id];}"
```

Also, instead of reading from a source file, I am just calling the address with &prog1 for the function CreateAndBuildProgram.

Here is the structure of the Visual Studio Project Tree:

```
--References
--External 
--Headers
--OpenCL
  --Template.cl
--Source Files
  --OpenCLProject3.cpp
  --utils.cpp
```

**Note that I have removed the error codes. If you generate a Code build project in visual studio 2015, you will get the exact same code and structure.**

Here is the host code (OpenCLProject3.cpp).

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <tchar.h>
    #include <memory.h>
    #include <vector>

    #include "CL\cl.h"
    #include "utils.h"

    //for perf. counters
    #include <Windows.h>


    // Macros for OpenCL versions
    #define OPENCL_VERSION_1_2  1.2f
    #define OPENCL_VERSION_2_0  2.0f

    struct ocl_args_d_t
    {
        ocl_args_d_t();
        ~ocl_args_d_t();

        // Regular OpenCL objects:
        cl_context       context;           // hold the context handler
        cl_device_id     device;            // hold the selected device handler
        cl_command_queue commandQueue;      // hold the commands-queue handler
        cl_program       program;           // hold the program handler
        cl_kernel        kernel;            // hold the kernel handler
        float            platformVersion;   // hold the OpenCL platform version (default 1.2)
        float            deviceVersion;     // hold the OpenCL device version (default. 1.2)
        float            compilerVersion;   // hold the device OpenCL C version (default. 1.2)

        // Objects that are specific for algorithm implemented in this sample
        cl_mem           srcA;              // hold first source buffer
        cl_mem           srcB;              // hold second source buffer
        cl_mem           dstMem;            // hold destination buffer
    };

    ocl_args_d_t::ocl_args_d_t():
            context(NULL),
            device(NULL),
            commandQueue(NULL),
            program(NULL),
            kernel(NULL),
            platformVersion(OPENCL_VERSION_1_2),
            deviceVersion(OPENCL_VERSION_1_2),
            compilerVersion(OPENCL_VERSION_1_2),
            srcA(NULL),
            srcB(NULL),
            dstMem(NULL)
    {
    }

    ocl_args_d_t::~ocl_args_d_t()
    {
        cl_int err = CL_SUCCESS;

        if (kernel)
        {
            err = clReleaseKernel(kernel);
            if (CL_SUCCESS != err)
            {
                LogError("Error: clReleaseKernel returned '%s'.\n", TranslateOpenCLError(err));
            }
        }
        if (program)
        {
            err = clReleaseProgram(program);
            if (CL_SUCCESS != err)
            {
                LogError("Error: clReleaseProgram returned '%s'.\n", TranslateOpenCLError(err));
            }
        }
        if (srcA)
        {
            err = clReleaseMemObject(srcA);
            if (CL_SUCCESS != err)
            {
                LogError("Error: clReleaseMemObject returned '%s'.\n", TranslateOpenCLError(err));
            }
        }
        if (srcB)
        {
            err = clReleaseMemObject(srcB);
            if (CL_SUCCESS != err)
            {
                LogError("Error: clReleaseMemObject returned '%s'.\n", TranslateOpenCLError(err));
            }
        }
        if (dstMem)
        {
            err = clReleaseMemObject(dstMem);
            if (CL_SUCCESS != err)
            {
                LogError("Error: clReleaseMemObject returned '%s'.\n", TranslateOpenCLError(err));
            }
        }
        if (commandQueue)
        {
            err = clReleaseCommandQueue(commandQueue);
            if (CL_SUCCESS != err)
            {
                LogError("Error: clReleaseCommandQueue returned '%s'.\n", TranslateOpenCLError(err));
            }
        }
        if (device)
        {
            err = clReleaseDevice(device);
            if (CL_SUCCESS != err)
            {
                LogError("Error: clReleaseDevice returned '%s'.\n", TranslateOpenCLError(err));
            }
        }
        if (context)
        {
            err = clReleaseContext(context);
            if (CL_SUCCESS != err)
            {
                LogError("Error: clReleaseContext returned '%s'.\n", TranslateOpenCLError(err));
            }
        }


    }


    bool CheckPreferredPlatformMatch(cl_platform_id platform, const char* preferredPlatform)
    {
        size_t stringLength = 0;
        cl_int err = CL_SUCCESS;
        bool match = false;

        // In order to read the platform's name, we first read the platform's name string length (param_value is NULL).
        // The value returned in stringLength
        err = clGetPlatformInfo(platform, CL_PLATFORM_NAME, 0, NULL, &stringLength);
        if (CL_SUCCESS != err)
        {
            LogError("Error: clGetPlatformInfo() to get CL_PLATFORM_NAME length returned '%s'.\n", TranslateOpenCLError(err));
            return false;
        }

        // Now, that we know the platform's name string length, we can allocate enough space before read it
        std::vector<char> platformName(stringLength);

        // Read the platform's name string
        // The read value returned in platformName
        err = clGetPlatformInfo(platform, CL_PLATFORM_NAME, stringLength, &platformName[0], NULL);
        if (CL_SUCCESS != err)
        {
            LogError("Error: clGetplatform_ids() to get CL_PLATFORM_NAME returned %s.\n", TranslateOpenCLError(err));
            return false;
        }

        // Now check if the platform's name is the required one
        if (strstr(&platformName[0], preferredPlatform) != 0)
        {
            // The checked platform is the one we're looking for
            match = true;
        }

        return match;
    }

    cl_platform_id FindOpenCLPlatform(const char* preferredPlatform, cl_device_type deviceType)
    {
        cl_uint numPlatforms = 0;
        cl_int err = CL_SUCCESS;

        // Get (in numPlatforms) the number of OpenCL platforms available
        // No platform ID will be return, since platforms is NULL
        err = clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &numPlatforms);
        if (CL_SUCCESS != err)
        {
            LogError("Error: clGetplatform_ids() to get num platforms returned %s.\n", TranslateOpenCLError(err));
            return NULL;
        }
        LogInfo("Number of available platforms: %u\n", numPlatforms);

        if (0 == numPlatforms)
        {
            LogError("Error: No platforms found!\n");
            return NULL;
        }

        std::vector<cl_platform_id> platforms(numPlatforms);

        // Now, obtains a list of numPlatforms OpenCL platforms available
        // The list of platforms available will be returned in platforms
        err = clGetPlatformIDs(numPlatforms, &platforms[0], NULL);
        if (CL_SUCCESS != err)
        {
            LogError("Error: clGetplatform_ids() to get platforms returned %s.\n", TranslateOpenCLError(err));
            return NULL;
        }

        // Check if one of the available platform matches the preferred requirements
        for (cl_uint i = 0; i < numPlatforms; i++)
        {
            bool match = true;
            cl_uint numDevices = 0;

            // If the preferredPlatform is not NULL then check if platforms[i] is the required one
            // Otherwise, continue the check with platforms[i]
            if ((NULL != preferredPlatform) && (strlen(preferredPlatform) > 0))
            {
                // In case we're looking for a specific platform
                match = CheckPreferredPlatformMatch(platforms[i], preferredPlatform);
            }

            // match is true if the platform's name is the required one or don't care (NULL)
            if (match)
            {
                // Obtains the number of deviceType devices available on platform
                // When the function failed we expect numDevices to be zero.
                // We ignore the function return value since a non-zero error code
                // could happen if this platform doesn't support the specified device type.
                err = clGetDeviceIDs(platforms[i], deviceType, 0, NULL, &numDevices);
                if (CL_SUCCESS != err)
                {
                    LogError("clGetDeviceIDs() returned %s.\n", TranslateOpenCLError(err));
                }

                if (0 != numDevices)
                {
                    // There is at list one device that answer the requirements
                    return platforms[i];
                }
            }
        }

        return NULL;
    }


    /*
     * This function read the OpenCL platdorm and device versions
     * (using clGetxxxInfo API) and stores it in the ocl structure.
     * Later it will enable us to support both OpenCL 1.2 and 2.0 platforms and devices
     * in the same program.
     */
    int GetPlatformAndDeviceVersion (cl_platform_id platformId, ocl_args_d_t *ocl)
    {
        cl_int err = CL_SUCCESS;

        // Read the platform's version string length (param_value is NULL).
        // The value returned in stringLength
        size_t stringLength = 0;
        err = clGetPlatformInfo(platformId, CL_PLATFORM_VERSION, 0, NULL, &stringLength);
        if (CL_SUCCESS != err)
        {
            LogError("Error: clGetPlatformInfo() to get CL_PLATFORM_VERSION length returned '%s'.\n", TranslateOpenCLError(err));
            return err;
        }

        // Now, that we know the platform's version string length, we can allocate enough space before read it
        std::vector<char> platformVersion(stringLength);

        // Read the platform's version string
        // The read value returned in platformVersion
        err = clGetPlatformInfo(platformId, CL_PLATFORM_VERSION, stringLength, &platformVersion[0], NULL);
        if (CL_SUCCESS != err)
        {
            LogError("Error: clGetplatform_ids() to get CL_PLATFORM_VERSION returned %s.\n", TranslateOpenCLError(err));
            return err;
        }

        if (strstr(&platformVersion[0], "OpenCL 2.0") != NULL)
        {
            ocl->platformVersion = OPENCL_VERSION_2_0;
        }

        // Read the device's version string length (param_value is NULL).
        err = clGetDeviceInfo(ocl->device, CL_DEVICE_VERSION, 0, NULL, &stringLength);
        if (CL_SUCCESS != err)
        {
            LogError("Error: clGetDeviceInfo() to get CL_DEVICE_VERSION length returned '%s'.\n", TranslateOpenCLError(err));
            return err;
        }

        // Now, that we know the device's version string length, we can allocate enough space before read it
        std::vector<char> deviceVersion(stringLength);

        // Read the device's version string
        // The read value returned in deviceVersion
        err = clGetDeviceInfo(ocl->device, CL_DEVICE_VERSION, stringLength, &deviceVersion[0], NULL);
        if (CL_SUCCESS != err)
        {
            LogError("Error: clGetDeviceInfo() to get CL_DEVICE_VERSION returned %s.\n", TranslateOpenCLError(err));
            return err;
        }

        if (strstr(&deviceVersion[0], "OpenCL 2.0") != NULL)
        {
            ocl->deviceVersion = OPENCL_VERSION_2_0;
        }

        // Read the device's OpenCL C version string length (param_value is NULL).
        err = clGetDeviceInfo(ocl->device, CL_DEVICE_OPENCL_C_VERSION, 0, NULL, &stringLength);
        if (CL_SUCCESS != err)
        {
            LogError("Error: clGetDeviceInfo() to get CL_DEVICE_OPENCL_C_VERSION length returned '%s'.\n", TranslateOpenCLError(err));
            return err;
        }

        // Now, that we know the device's OpenCL C version string length, we can allocate enough space before read it
        std::vector<char> compilerVersion(stringLength);

        // Read the device's OpenCL C version string
        // The read value returned in compilerVersion
        err = clGetDeviceInfo(ocl->device, CL_DEVICE_OPENCL_C_VERSION, stringLength, &compilerVersion[0], NULL);
        if (CL_SUCCESS != err)
        {
            LogError("Error: clGetDeviceInfo() to get CL_DEVICE_OPENCL_C_VERSION returned %s.\n", TranslateOpenCLError(err));
            return err;
        }

        else if (strstr(&compilerVersion[0], "OpenCL C 2.0") != NULL)
        {
            ocl->compilerVersion = OPENCL_VERSION_2_0;
        }

        return err;
    }


    /*
     * Generate random value for input buffers
     */
    void generateInput(cl_int* inputArray, cl_uint arrayWidth, cl_uint arrayHeight)
    {
        srand(12345);

        // random initialization of input
        cl_uint array_size = arrayWidth * arrayHeight;
        for (cl_uint i = 0; i < array_size; ++i)
        {
            inputArray[i] = rand();
        }
    }

    int SetupOpenCL(ocl_args_d_t *ocl, cl_device_type deviceType)
    {
        // The following variable stores return codes for all OpenCL calls.
        cl_int err = CL_SUCCESS;

        // Query for all available OpenCL platforms on the system
        // Here you enumerate all platforms and pick one which name has preferredPlatform as a sub-string
        cl_platform_id platformId = FindOpenCLPlatform("Intel", deviceType);
        if (NULL == platformId)
        {
            LogError("Error: Failed to find OpenCL platform.\n");
            return CL_INVALID_VALUE;
        }

        // Create context with device of specified type.
        // Required device type is passed as function argument deviceType.
        // So you may use this function to create context for any CPU or GPU OpenCL device.
        // The creation is synchronized (pfn_notify is NULL) and NULL user_data
        cl_context_properties contextProperties[] = {CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, (cl_context_properties)platformId, 0};
        ocl->context = clCreateContextFromType(contextProperties, deviceType, NULL, NULL, &err);
        if ((CL_SUCCESS != err) || (NULL == ocl->context))
        {
            LogError("Couldn't create a context, clCreateContextFromType() returned '%s'.\n", TranslateOpenCLError(err));
            return err;
        }

        // Query for OpenCL device which was used for context creation
        err = clGetContextInfo(ocl->context, CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES, sizeof(cl_device_id), &ocl->device, NULL);
        if (CL_SUCCESS != err)
        {
            LogError("Error: clGetContextInfo() to get list of devices returned %s.\n", TranslateOpenCLError(err));
            return err;
        }

        // Read the OpenCL platform's version and the device OpenCL and OpenCL C versions
        GetPlatformAndDeviceVersion(platformId, ocl);

        // Create command queue.
        // OpenCL kernels are enqueued for execution to a particular device through special objects called command queues.
        // Command queue guarantees some ordering between calls and other OpenCL commands.
        // Here you create a simple in-order OpenCL command queue that doesn't allow execution of two kernels in parallel on a target device.
    #ifdef CL_VERSION_2_0
        if (OPENCL_VERSION_2_0 == ocl->deviceVersion)
        {
            const cl_command_queue_properties properties[] = {CL_QUEUE_PROPERTIES, CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE, 0};
            ocl->commandQueue = clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties(ocl->context, ocl->device, properties, &err);
        } 
        else {
            // default behavior: OpenCL 1.2
            cl_command_queue_properties properties = CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE;
            ocl->commandQueue = clCreateCommandQueue(ocl->context, ocl->device, properties, &err);
        } 
    #else
        // default behavior: OpenCL 1.2
        cl_command_queue_properties properties = CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE;
        ocl->commandQueue = clCreateCommandQueue(ocl->context, ocl->device, properties, &err);
    #endif
        if (CL_SUCCESS != err)
        {
            LogError("Error: clCreateCommandQueue() returned %s.\n", TranslateOpenCLError(err));
            return err;
        }

        return CL_SUCCESS;
    }


    /* 
     * Create and build OpenCL program from its source code
     */
    int CreateAndBuildProgram(ocl_args_d_t *ocl)
    {
        cl_int err = CL_SUCCESS;

        // Upload the OpenCL C source code from the input file to source
        // The size of the C program is returned in sourceSize
        char* source = NULL;
        size_t src_size = 0;
        err = ReadSourceFromFile("Template.cl", &source, &src_size);
        if (CL_SUCCESS != err)
        {
            LogError("Error: ReadSourceFromFile returned %s.\n", TranslateOpenCLError(err));
            goto Finish;
        }

        // And now after you obtained a regular C string call clCreateProgramWithSource to create OpenCL program object.
        ocl->program = clCreateProgramWithSource(ocl->context, 1, (const char**)&source, &src_size, &err);
        if (CL_SUCCESS != err)
        {
            LogError("Error: clCreateProgramWithSource returned %s.\n", TranslateOpenCLError(err));
            goto Finish;
        }

        // Build the program
        // During creation a program is not built. You need to explicitly call build function.
        // Here you just use create-build sequence,
        // but there are also other possibilities when program consist of several parts,
        // some of which are libraries, and you may want to consider using clCompileProgram and clLinkProgram as
        // alternatives.
        err = clBuildProgram(ocl->program, 1, &ocl->device, "", NULL, NULL);
        if (CL_SUCCESS != err)
        {
            LogError("Error: clBuildProgram() for source program returned %s.\n", TranslateOpenCLError(err));

            // In case of error print the build log to the standard output
            // First check the size of the log
            // Then allocate the memory and obtain the log from the program
            if (err == CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE)
            {
                size_t log_size = 0;
                clGetProgramBuildInfo(ocl->program, ocl->device, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, 0, NULL, &log_size);

                std::vector<char> build_log(log_size);
                clGetProgramBuildInfo(ocl->program, ocl->device, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, log_size, &build_log[0], NULL);

                LogError("Error happened during the build of OpenCL program.\nBuild log:%s", &build_log[0]);
            }
        }

    Finish:
        if (source)
        {
            delete[] source;
            source = NULL;
        }

        return err;
    }


    int CreateBufferArguments(ocl_args_d_t *ocl, cl_int* inputA, cl_int* inputB, cl_int* outputC, cl_uint arrayWidth, cl_uint arrayHeight)
    {
        cl_int err = CL_SUCCESS;

        // Create new OpenCL buffer objects
        // As these buffer are used only for read by the kernel, you are recommended to create it with flag CL_MEM_READ_ONLY.
        // Always set minimal read/write flags for buffers, it may lead to better performance because it allows runtime
        // to better organize data copying.
        // You use CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR here, because the buffers should be populated with bytes at inputA and inputB.

        ocl->srcA = clCreateBuffer(ocl->context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR, sizeof(cl_uint) * arrayWidth * arrayHeight, inputA, &err);
        if (CL_SUCCESS != err)
        {
            LogError("Error: clCreateBuffer for srcA returned %s\n", TranslateOpenCLError(err));
            return err;
        }

        ocl->srcB = clCreateBuffer(ocl->context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR, sizeof(cl_uint) * arrayWidth * arrayHeight, inputB, &err);
        if (CL_SUCCESS != err)
        {
            LogError("Error: clCreateBuffer for srcB returned %s\n", TranslateOpenCLError(err));
            return err;
        }

        // If the output buffer is created directly on top of output buffer using CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR,
        // then, depending on the OpenCL runtime implementation and hardware capabilities, 
        // it may save you not necessary data copying.
        // As it is known that output buffer will be write only, you explicitly declare it using CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY.
        ocl->dstMem = clCreateBuffer(ocl->context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY | CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR, sizeof(cl_uint) * arrayWidth * arrayHeight, outputC, &err);
        if (CL_SUCCESS != err)
        {
            LogError("Error: clCreateBuffer for dstMem returned %s\n", TranslateOpenCLError(err));
            return err;
        }


        return CL_SUCCESS;
    }


    cl_uint SetKernelArguments(ocl_args_d_t *ocl)
    {
        cl_int err = CL_SUCCESS;

        err  =  clSetKernelArg(ocl->kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&ocl->srcA);
        if (CL_SUCCESS != err)
        {
            LogError("error: Failed to set argument srcA, returned %s\n", TranslateOpenCLError(err));
            return err;
        }

        err  = clSetKernelArg(ocl->kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&ocl->srcB);
        if (CL_SUCCESS != err)
        {
            LogError("Error: Failed to set argument srcB, returned %s\n", TranslateOpenCLError(err));
            return err;
        }

        err  = clSetKernelArg(ocl->kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&ocl->dstMem);
        if (CL_SUCCESS != err)
        {
            LogError("Error: Failed to set argument dstMem, returned %s\n", TranslateOpenCLError(err));
            return err;
        }

        return err;
    }


    /*
     * Execute the kernel
     */
    cl_uint ExecuteAddKernel(ocl_args_d_t *ocl, cl_uint width, cl_uint height)
    {
        cl_int err = CL_SUCCESS;

        // Define global iteration space for clEnqueueNDRangeKernel.
        size_t globalWorkSize[2] = {width, height};


        // execute kernel
        err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(ocl->commandQueue, ocl->kernel, 2, NULL, globalWorkSize, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
        if (CL_SUCCESS != err)
        {
            LogError("Error: Failed to run kernel, return %s\n", TranslateOpenCLError(err));
            return err;
        }

        // Wait until the queued kernel is completed by the device
        err = clFinish(ocl->commandQueue);
        if (CL_SUCCESS != err)
        {
            LogError("Error: clFinish return %s\n", TranslateOpenCLError(err));
            return err;
        }

        return CL_SUCCESS;
    }


    /*
     * "Read" the result buffer (mapping the buffer to the host memory address)
     */
    bool ReadAndVerify(ocl_args_d_t *ocl, cl_uint width, cl_uint height, cl_int *inputA, cl_int *inputB)
    {
        cl_int err = CL_SUCCESS;
        bool result = true;

        // Enqueue a command to map the buffer object (ocl->dstMem) into the host address space and returns a pointer to it
        // The map operation is blocking
        cl_int *resultPtr = (cl_int *)clEnqueueMapBuffer(ocl->commandQueue, ocl->dstMem, true, CL_MAP_READ, 0, sizeof(cl_uint) * width * height, 0, NULL, NULL, &err);

        if (CL_SUCCESS != err)
        {
            LogError("Error: clEnqueueMapBuffer returned %s\n", TranslateOpenCLError(err));
            return false;
        }

        // Call clFinish to guarantee that output region is updated
        err = clFinish(ocl->commandQueue);
        if (CL_SUCCESS != err)
        {
            LogError("Error: clFinish returned %s\n", TranslateOpenCLError(err));
        }

        // We mapped dstMem to resultPtr, so resultPtr is ready and includes the kernel output !!!
        // Verify the results
        unsigned int size = width * height;
        for (unsigned int k = 0; k < size; ++k)
        {
            if (resultPtr[k] != inputA[k] + inputB[k])
            {
                LogError("Verification failed at %d: (%d + %d = %d)\n", k, inputA[k], inputB[k], resultPtr[k]);
                result = false;
            }
        }

         // Unmapped the output buffer before releasing it
        err = clEnqueueUnmapMemObject(ocl->commandQueue, ocl->dstMem, resultPtr, 0, NULL, NULL);
        if (CL_SUCCESS != err)
        {
            LogError("Error: clEnqueueUnmapMemObject returned %s\n", TranslateOpenCLError(err));
        }

        return result;
    }


    /*
     * main execution routine
     * Basically it consists of three parts:
     *   - generating the inputs
     *   - running OpenCL kernel
     *   - reading results of processing
     */
    int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[])
    {
        cl_int err;
        ocl_args_d_t ocl;
        cl_device_type deviceType = CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU;

        LARGE_INTEGER perfFrequency;
        LARGE_INTEGER performanceCountNDRangeStart;
        LARGE_INTEGER performanceCountNDRangeStop;

        cl_uint arrayWidth  = 1024;
        cl_uint arrayHeight = 1024;

        //initialize Open CL objects (context, queue, etc.)
        if (CL_SUCCESS != SetupOpenCL(&ocl, deviceType))
        {
            return -1;
        }

        // allocate working buffers. 
        // the buffer should be aligned with 4K page and size should fit 64-byte cached line
        cl_uint optimizedSize = ((sizeof(cl_int) * arrayWidth * arrayHeight - 1)/64 + 1) * 64;
        cl_int* inputA  = (cl_int*)_aligned_malloc(optimizedSize, 4096);
        cl_int* inputB  = (cl_int*)_aligned_malloc(optimizedSize, 4096);
        cl_int* outputC = (cl_int*)_aligned_malloc(optimizedSize, 4096);
        if (NULL == inputA || NULL == inputB || NULL == outputC)
        {
            LogError("Error: _aligned_malloc failed to allocate buffers.\n");
            return -1;
        }

        //random input
        generateInput(inputA, arrayWidth, arrayHeight);
        generateInput(inputB, arrayWidth, arrayHeight);

        // Create OpenCL buffers from host memory
        // These buffers will be used later by the OpenCL kernel
        if (CL_SUCCESS != CreateBufferArguments(&ocl, inputA, inputB, outputC, arrayWidth, arrayHeight))
        {
            return -1;
        }

         // Create and build the OpenCL program
        if (CL_SUCCESS != CreateAndBuildProgram(&ocl))
        {
            return -1;
        }

        // Program consists of kernels.
        // Each kernel can be called (enqueued) from the host part of OpenCL application.
        // To call the kernel, you need to create it from existing program.
        ocl.kernel = clCreateKernel(ocl.program, "Add", &err);
        if (CL_SUCCESS != err)
        {
            LogError("Error: clCreateKernel returned %s\n", TranslateOpenCLError(err));
            return -1;
        }

        // Passing arguments into OpenCL kernel.
        if (CL_SUCCESS != SetKernelArguments(&ocl))
        {
            return -1;
        }

        // Regularly you wish to use OpenCL in your application to achieve greater performance results
        // that are hard to achieve in other ways.
        // To understand those performance benefits you may want to measure time your application spent in OpenCL kernel execution.
        // The recommended way to obtain this time is to measure interval between two moments:
        //   - just before clEnqueueNDRangeKernel is called, and
        //   - just after clFinish is called
        // clFinish is necessary to measure entire time spending in the kernel, measuring just clEnqueueNDRangeKernel is not enough,
        // because this call doesn't guarantees that kernel is finished.
        // clEnqueueNDRangeKernel is just enqueue new command in OpenCL command queue and doesn't wait until it ends.
        // clFinish waits until all commands in command queue are finished, that suits your need to measure time.
        bool queueProfilingEnable = true;
        if (queueProfilingEnable)
            QueryPerformanceCounter(&performanceCountNDRangeStart);
        // Execute (enqueue) the kernel
        if (CL_SUCCESS != ExecuteAddKernel(&ocl, arrayWidth, arrayHeight))
        {
            return -1;
        }
        if (queueProfilingEnable)
            QueryPerformanceCounter(&performanceCountNDRangeStop);

        // The last part of this function: getting processed results back.
        // use map-unmap sequence to update original memory area with output buffer.
        ReadAndVerify(&ocl, arrayWidth, arrayHeight, inputA, inputB);

        // retrieve performance counter frequency
        if (queueProfilingEnable)
        {
            QueryPerformanceFrequency(&perfFrequency);
            LogInfo("NDRange performance counter time %f ms.\n",
                1000.0f*(float)(performanceCountNDRangeStop.QuadPart - performanceCountNDRangeStart.QuadPart) / (float)perfFrequency.QuadPart);
        }

        _aligned_free(inputA);
        _aligned_free(inputB);
        _aligned_free(outputC);

        return 0;
    }
```

Here is the kernel code (Template.cl):

```
__kernel void Add(__global int* pA, __global int* pB, __global int* pC)
{
    const int x     = get_global_id(0);
    const int y     = get_global_id(1);
    const int width = get_global_size(0);

    const int id = y * width + x;

    pC[id] = pA[id] + pB[id];
}
```

Comment: it may be you can post formatted code for better readability? it's not really clear from where the error comes from.

Comment: Sure. I'll add everything it gives me. Well, atleast the cpp and cl file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be a duplicate of this here:

[OpenCL code 'Error MSB3721' for Intel OpenCL SDK on Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21697053/opencl-code-error-msb3721-for-intel-opencl-sdk-on-visual-studio-2010)

Possible solution was to remove the '.cl' file from the project.

Comment: Yep! It works, but that is a weird solution...maybe a visual studio bug?

Comment: Not really a bug. For all the files in the project, VS needs to know what to do with them when the project is built. For .cl file, VS does not know what to do with it, hence the error. And since VS does not need to do anything, the solution is to remove the file from the project. It may also be possible to instruct VS to ignore this file during build via some project settings, but I did not try that.